# Safari not taking on the transition properties from added class

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

[Fiddle for testing (click the black container)](https://jsfiddle.net/vuwkj6fo/2/)

I have an animation I'm coding using a series of divs from which I am adding and removing classes. The animation is complete, and works as it should in Firefox and Chrome. However, I am having a problem with it in Safari: The objects are not taking on the `transition` properties from the new added classes, and only using the `transition` properties from it's initial class.

For example:

[image]

The div has both the `.circle` class, and the `.circle.grow` class, which is added when I want to make the circle div bigger. You can see in the grow class, The div has taken on the `transform` property of `.grow`, in which it's scale is returned to (1,1). However, the `transition` included in `.grow`, which would transition the scale is not added, and it instead sticks with the initial `transition` property present in `.circle`, which does not transition the transform property. As a result, when `.grow` is added, the circle simply jumps to the new scale.

As mentioned, it works perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari, taking on `.grow`'s transition property. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

**Edit 1:** after a bit more testing, I have tried removing the `transition` properties from the initial circle class. HOWEVER, when adding the `circle.grow` class, the `transition` properties are still being crossed out, and none of them are applied, despite there not being anything that it's reverting to. Perhaps how the `transition` property is being defined in `.circle.grow` is invalid somehow to Safari? Presumably, I can put the `transition` property back in the base `.circle` class, and it WOULD be overwritten by `.cricle.grow`, if it's `transition` was valid. But it's not (?)

SO: what is wrong with the code:

```
transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
-moz-transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
```

that is making Safari not read or execute it?

Comment: Have you tried setting them to different durations and seeing if it is still the case? It may have to do with the fact that they are the same exact style.

Comment: @Rorschach120 Just tried, no effect. In any case, they aren't the same transitions; one is `transform 0.3s, width 0.3s`, the other is `width 0.3s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I've solved it! It's a strange problem considering it worked otherwise in Chrome / FF, but should have been obvious.

The solution was simple: Safari will only execute -webkit- transitions. But when it tried to, one of them was the transform property, which Safari did not accept. All I needed to do was add the vendor prefix for each `transform` in their respective vendor-prefixed `transition`s. Like so:

```
transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a syntax issue.

CSS:

```
.circle.grow {
    transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, width 0.3s;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1,1);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1,1);
}
```